# JMeter: How to write regular expression extractor for this request URL

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

> (//test-clinicalpl.hee.heaelth.nz/nzty/?encryptedRequest=B3616B90E8CD11B90E99022FE7998834453B92493671C1AF3DB24346493F5364579EF1E9A9FED64B25E1593A3EF768A887B89E5A5A73EDD7BD6D88A1C4ED2D0E994820BEE64B410113603687174086C8B0FEEFF051774184&mac=6252A91F473FD4F4C66E17A7928AFAA48E0E612A&expiry=0000016954D411EC

`encryptedRequest`, `mac` and `expiry` are the dynamic values changes everytime

I wrote this as there regular expression extractor as below:
`encryptedRequest= (.*?)&  mac=(.*?)&    expiry=(.*?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the request and add post processor: [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).
2. Use this RegExp
   `encryptedRequest=(.*)&mac=(.*)&expiry=(.*)`
3. Specify Variable name, `myEncryptedRequest` for example
4. Set Template - `$1$` for the first matching (`$2$` - for the second `mac`, etc).
5. Use this values in next requests as `${myEncryptedRequest}`
6. You may add more Regula Expression Extractors to parse another values.

   Please refer to [JMeter component reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) for more details and [Guide how to extract and re-use as variable](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)